# GWT make virtual keyboard

Tags: gwt

I have  popup panel with keyboard buttons. The task is to enter text in textfiled of Login popup panel on button click.
I have tried to fire key up and press event, but it doesnt write text in field.

```
        final KeyButton keyBut = new KeyButton(smallBut.toString(),smButprs.toString(),codeBut,isShift);
        keyBut.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                txtBox.setFocus(true);
                DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createKeyDownEvent(false, false, keyBut.isShiftKeyDown(), false,keyBut.getKeyCode()), txtBox);
                DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createKeyUpEvent(false, false, keyBut.isShiftKeyDown(), false,keyBut.getKeyCode()), txtBox);
                DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createKeyPressEvent(false, false, keyBut.isShiftKeyDown(), false,keyBut.getKeyCode()), txtBox);
                //DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createKeyPressEvent(false, false, keyBut.isShiftKeyDown(), false,68), txtBox);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
keyBut.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // If this is a button for "a"
        textBox.setValue(textBox.getValue() + "a");
    }

});
```

Comment: I khow about this solution. But I have buttons like CAPS LOCK,ENTER and it would need another decisions. And if I could send event it would simple.

Comment: Why?! You can check if CAPS LOCK is pressed, and add "A" instead of "a". And you can add a new line symbol if ENTER is clicked. Why go for a more complex solution when it can be done in one line of code?